# Нужно проверить: есть ли в базе WebSQL пользователь с введёнными логином и паролем?

Tags: javascript, button, frontend, websqldatabase

Нужно проверить: есть ли в базе WebSQL пользователь с введёнными логином и паролем? Проблема заключается в том, что данные, которые есть в БД не находятся при запросе. Как исправить? Может что-то не так? Код прикрепляю ниже:

```
(function () {
 var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
 submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitButtonHandler);

function submitButtonHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var inputLogin = document.getElementById("login");
    var inputPassword = document.getElementById("password");

    db = openDatabase("usersDB", "0.1", "A list of users", 100);
    if(!db) {alert("Failed to connect to database."); }

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersDB", [],
            function (result) {alert("aaaa")},
            function (tx, errror) {alert("qqqq")});
    })
}

})();
```

Comment: А этот запрос работает не из JS -кода: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersDB`? У Вас имя базы данных совпадает с таблицей, там нет опечатки? Что в результате у Вас получается? Какой код ошибки или сообщение? У Вас `inputLogin` и `inputPassword` не используются в запросе, кстати. В запросе простая выборка количества записей в таблице `usersDB`.

Comment: Приведите так же код создания БД или апгрейда ее версии, то где создается таблица `usersDB`